# Function implementing

Tags: typescript

```
function f(str: string): number;
function f(num: number): string;
function f(strOrNum: string | number): number | string {
  if (typeof strOrNum === 'string') {
    return +strOrNum;
  } else {
    return strOrNum + '';
  }
}
```

Why is the return value of the implementation function with union types is not compatible with function overloading? Must any type be returned?

Comment: A version issue? TS Playground seems to not show any error: https://tsplay.dev/wEVbyN

Comment: I reuse the interface to constrain an object, Check it for me:https://tsplay.dev/mZ8zow